# Nodejs_Socket called from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have this script that is usually used in the same place with the server launch in `server.js` what I tried now is to separate this script from the main file so I copied the script `socketIo` from server.js and moved it into another file `index.js` as below

```
//index.js 
exports.connectSocket = (socket) => {
  const userSocketIdMap = new Map();

  UserOnline.push({ id: userCount++, user: socket.id });

  console.log("We have a new connection!", {
    userCount: userCount,
    UserOnline,
  });
  socket.on("join", ({ name, channel }, callback) => {}))}
```

and in the server.js  I did this

```
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const io = socketio(server);
const socketConnect = require("./index");
//run when client connects
io.on("connection", socketConnect);
```

the problem that I'm keep getting this error

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
events.js:117
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object
```

anyidea how to achieve calling socket io to run from different file

best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You should require the `connectSocket` function like this:

using

```js
const { connectSocket } = require("./index");
io.on("connection", connectSocket);
```

The second parameter of `io.on('connection', listener)` is a function. You are passing an object. That's why you got the error. The value of `socketConnect` is `{ connectSocket }`. So you need to use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get `connectSocket` function.